# How to customize histogram using seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn's `FacetGrid` to do multiple histogram plots from a dataframe (`plot_df`) on the parameter - "xyz". But I want to do the following additional things too in those plots,

1. Create a vertical axes line at x-value = 0
2. Color all the bins that are equal to or lesser than 0 (on x-axis) with a different shade
3. Calculate the percentage area of the histogram for only those bins that are below 0 (on x-axis)

I am able to get lot of examples online but not with seaborn FacetGrid option

````py
g = sns.FacetGrid(plot_df, col='xyz', height=5)```

g.map(plt.hist, "slack", bins=50)
````

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the generated axes (`for xyz, ax in g.axes_dict.items(): ....`) and call your plotting functions for each of those axes.

Or, you could call `g.map_dataframe(...)` with a custom function. That function will need to draw onto the "current ax".

Changing the x and y labels, needs to be done after the call to `g.map_dataframe()` because seaborn erases the x and y labels at the end of that functions.

You can call `plt.setp(g.axes, xlabel='data', ylabel='frequency')` to set the labels for all the subplots. Or `g.set_ylabels('...')` to only set the y labels for the "outer" subplots.

Here is some example code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def individual_plot(**kwargs):
     ax = plt.gca()  # get the current ax
     data = kwargs['data']['slack'].values
     xmin, xmax = data.min(), data.max()
     bin_width = xmax / 50
     # histogram part > 0
     ax.hist(data, bins=np.arange(0.000001, xmax + 0.001, bin_width), color='tomato')
     # histogram part < 0
     ax.hist(data, bins=-np.arange(0, abs(xmin) + bin_width + 0.001, bin_width)[::-1], color='lime')
     # line at x=0
     ax.axvline(0, color='navy', ls='--')
     # calculate and show part < 0
     percent_under_zero = sum(data <= 0) / len(data) * 100
     ax.text(0.5, 0.98, f'part < 0: {percent_under_zero:.1f} %',
             color='k', ha='center', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes)

# first generate some test data
plot_df = pd.DataFrame({'xyz': np.repeat([*'xyz'], 1000),
                        'slack': np.random.randn(3000) * 10 + np.random.choice([10, 500], 3000, p=[0.9, 0.1])})

g = sns.FacetGrid(plot_df, col='xyz', height=5)
g.map_dataframe(individual_plot)
plt.setp(g.axes, xlabel='data', ylabel='frequency')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.FacetGrid with cumstomized plots]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for the solution. Its exactly what I wanted but when I try to understand and reproduce at my end I am having some difficulty. Especially the "kwargs['data']" statement is not clear. Could you please clarify what is the variable name under which the "plot_df" dataframe is passed to the function?

Comment: `map_dataframe(individual_plot)` will call `individual_plot(data=...)` with the dataframe given to `FacetGrid` but restricted to the subset that belongs to the given subplot. Something similar to `individual_plot(data=plot_data[plot_data['xyz'] == 'x'])` for the first subplot.  `kwargs['data']` gets the argument to `individual_plot` that is called data.  `**kwargs` is used because `map_dataframe` can send more parameters (e.g. the color).  See e.g. [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) for more information about `kwargs`.

Comment: Thanks again, this really clears all my doubts and solves the problem. Appreciate the details!

Comment: One more question, I was trying to add x and y labels for each of those 3 subplots using the following command inside the "individual_plot" function, but it didn't help. Could you please advise what is the right way to do this? ```ax.set(xlabel="Data", ylabel="Frequency")```

Comment: The problem is that at the end of `g.map_dataframe`, seaborn erases the x and y labels again.  You can set them afterwards via `plt.setp(g.axes, xlabel='data', ylabel='frequency')`

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend any good tutorial reference for plotting using seaborn in python? For example some the solutions which you have given like plt.setp and map_dataframe usage are hard to decipher from the standard command documentation

Comment: The official seaborn pages contain some examples that can serve as tutorials, together with stackoverflow answers to find more details.  Also, Kimberly Fessel's [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCirb0k3PnuQnRjh8tTJHJuA) contains many interesting tips and tricks for [a lot of seaborn functions](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtPIclEQf-3cG31dxSMZ8KTcDG7zYng1j) (and also more general data visualization videos)